# UV Texture Error

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I downloaded this model from Mario Kart and the UV came out like this in multiples. I don't really know how to deal with a UV that comes out like this. The concept is to only have that one pupil in the eye, but how do I subtract the others without making that one disappear too. I tried using blend types to but nothing work. Anyone know what options to press to fix this?

Model Download Link: https://www.models-resource.com/wii_u/mariokart8/model/9758/

Comment: Any chance you can link us where you downloaded it from? Assuming of course it is free and open-source

Comment: Looks like a face around left eye on the UV map is overlapping with another one. Unfortunately there's no way to lnow exactly without model or at least screenshots of the UV map overlayed on texture and mesh in Edit mode.

Comment: It's in the question now.